# Jenkins build status icons on GitHub Pull requests

Tags: github, jenkins

I am integrating Jenkins with GitHub and have successfully set Jenkins to build after a GitHub push. But another thing I would like to establish is the build status icons(green check, yellow circle for pending, red "x") on the Pull request page. How do I go about to show these icons?

Here's an example from apple's swift pull request page:

[image: example]

Comment: Have a look at [tag:jenkins-pipeline], this does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you need to add Jenkins plugins:

1. [github-request-builder](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) sets the build status of a given `PR` in GitHub.  [This post](https://www.theguild.nl/building-github-pull-requests-with-jenkins/) is a good guide for setting it up.
2. [embeddable-build-status](https://plugins.jenkins.io/embeddable-build-status) hosts a project-wide image showing your overall build status:

[image]

Comment: Hey Derek, thanks for the input. I tried this earlier, and while it does work, I believe this is the build status badge for the whole project in Readme.md for example. I'm looking for a way for GitHub to show the build status of each pull request as per the example image I provided on the top. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, I got it to work using github pull request builder.

Comment: The build status badge is not the answer to the question IMHO

Comment: @StephenKing You're right, I guess it's half-correct then. I'll look into your answer of using jenkins-pipeline, thanks.